# Trying to loop through columns to produce a table for each

Tags: r, function, dataframe, for-loop, sapply

I have a table with 10 columns. The columns have the following names: "Month", "Year", "Advising", "Hang Out", "Food", "Printing", "Supplies", "Studying", "Lending Library", "Other"

I want to loop through each of the Reason Columns and create a table broken up by month in the Y and year in the X and the sum for that Reason category.

I have attempted to create a for loop and use the sapply/lapply family of functions.  However, I cannot move past "Advising." But if I run my function on each individual column it does work.

```
# Sample Data
AttendanceTab <- data.frame(Month = c("Oct", "Nov", "Oct", "Jan", "Feb", 
                                      "Mar", "May", "Oct"), 
                            Year = c( 2018, 2017, 2017, 2019, 2018, 2019, 
                                      2018, 2017), 
                            Advising = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
                            Hang.Out = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0),
                            Food = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1))
```

```
attendance_summary <- function(ReasonName, FUN = sum) {
                    tapply(AttendanceTab[, ReasonName], 
                    AttendanceTab[,1:2], sum)
}
```

```
attendance_summary("Advising") 
attendance_summary("Hang.Out")
attendance_summary("Food")
attendance_summary("Printing")
attendance_summary("Supplies")
attendance_summary("Studying")
attendance_summary("Lending.Library")
attendance_summary("Other")
```

```
Complexes <- dim(AttendanceTab)[2]

reasons <- as.character(c("Advising", "Hang Out", "Food", 
          "Printing", "Supplies", "Studying", "Lending Library", 
          "Other"))
```

```
for(i in 1:Complexes) {
                    RR <- reasons[[i]]
                    ADSum <- attendance_summary(RR)
                    print(ADSum)
}
```

```
sapply(AttendanceTab, attendance_summary)
 #Also tried
sapply(reasons, attendance_summary)
```

for example reasons[[1]] works and gives the appropriate table, but when it moves on to the second reasons element, it returns:

Error in `[.data.frame`(attendance2, , ReasonName) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including some example data, in a plain text format, and an example of the desired output.

Comment: Thank you! I just added some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo when defining `reasons`. In `AttendanceTab` you have the column `Hang.Out` and in `reasons` you call it `Hang Out` - `space` instead of `.`.
To avoid this, you can use

```
reasons <- names(AttendanceTab)[-c(1:2)]
Complexes <- length(reasons)
```

Comment: The typo was the issue. Thank you, I will make the corrections.